# I can't get my uploaded fonts to work on my site title

Tags: wordpress, css, fonts, font-face

I can change the colour of a title fine but having difficultly changing the font face so it can use all the different type of fonts (i.e .eot, .svg, .tff, .woff and .woff2).

All my font files are saved on the web server: /httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb

and so I have put the following in the file in the style.css: (\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\leeway\style.css)

```
#logo .site-title {
    font-family: 'fofbb', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
       src: url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.eot') format("embedded-opentype"), 
         url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.woff') format("woff"), 
         url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.ttf') format("truetype"), 
         url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.svg') format("svg");
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.15em 0;
    font-size: 2.7em;
    color: #92f442; }
#logo .site-title a:link,
#logo .site-title a:visited {
    font-family: 'fofbb', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
       src: url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.eot') format("embedded-opentype"), 
         url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.woff') format("woff"), 
         url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.ttf') format("truetype"), 
         url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.svg') format("svg");
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.15em 0;
    color: #92f442;}
#logo .site-title a:hover,
#logo .site-title a:active {
    font-family: 'fofbb', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
       src: url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.eot') format("embedded-opentype"), 
         url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.woff') format("woff"), 
         url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.ttf') format("truetype"), 
         url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.svg') format("svg");
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.15em 0;
    color: #92f442;
    text-decoration: none;}
```

I know that I am definitely changing the correct element as when I change it's colour that changes OK.

Can anyone let me know what is wrong with my code and why my new font not showing?

Cheers,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your font as *fofbb* only. i.e *fofbb.woff*, *fofbb.tff* etc.

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add your fonts using `@font-face` -like this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "fofbb";
          src: url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.eot') format("embedded-opentype"), 
               url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.woff') format("woff"), 
               url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.ttf') format("truetype"), 
               url('../httpdocs/wp-content/themes/leeway/css/fofbb/fofbb_reg-webfont.svg') format("svg");
}

#logo .site-title {
  font-family: "fofbb"
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <div class="site-title">site title</div>
</div>
```

Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) for more information about `@font-face` rule.

Comment: Thanks guys, but this still does not seem to work as when I'm in Google inspect the code the controls the style seemed to be crossed out. On looking up this problem up it states that:

'When a CSS property shows as struck-through, it means that the crossed-out style was applied, but then overridden by a more specific selector, a more local rule, or by a later property within the same rule.'

Is there a way to find the piece of code the is effectively 'quashing' my code? Is it higher up in the code structure?

Thanks